# why my WSO2 EC2 linux box running out of space

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have hosted WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Idenity server in AWS Ec2 instance.
Now its running out of memory.
I have cleared logs and tried ; but its still lacking space.
I got solutions on how to increase the size.But I want to know if there is something which i am missing. May be is there some configuration or temp directories which i should be clearing?

My df command shows the below output and /dev/xvda1  is fully user

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         16G   56K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      9.8G  9.7G     0 100% /
```

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37221/finding-files-that-use-the-most-disk-space) and find where the biggest files are.  Remember that removing a files may not release the space back to the file system if the file is still in use.

Comment: I am assuming you are facing memory issue, check JVM Xms and Xmx configuration in <product-home>/bin/wso2server.sh. Next this also could be due to restriction on number of threads a linux user can create. Check /etc/security/limits.conf (details https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127557/increasing-nproc-limit-for-a-non-root-user-only-effective-by-restart).  Also check /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf
Add user non root user in this file. Details are here : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/406663